# Ruby On rails Filter number min and max

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I need when I type minimum number and the maximum number to show all the cars in between something like this https://www.lpauto.ca/used-cars-vancouver?Makes=Audi

Here is my form

```
<%= form_for "",url: cars_path, role: "search", method: :get do %>
     <%= text_field_tag :searchp, @search_pricen_term,placeholder: "Min..." %>
     <%= text_field_tag :searchpx, @search_pricex_term,placeholder: "Max..." %> 
<% end %>
```

In the controller in index

```
if params[:searchp]
  @search_pricen_term = params[:searchp]
  @cars= @cars.search_by(@search_pricen_term)
end
```

In the model

```
def self.search_by(search_pricen_term)
  where("price <= :search_pricen_term OR price >= :search_pricex_term ",
  search_pricen_term: search_pricen_term )
end
```

Comment: What does `params[:searchp]` look like?

Comment: Note that your current  `where` condition doesn't make sense, since you use `:search_pricen_term` twice and every price will be either greater or equal OR less than or equal to that.

Comment: Improved code formatting.

Comment: I did some edit to my codes (searchp mean search by price, search_pricen_term mean search by minimum price, search_pricex_term mean search maximum price)

Comment: So, doesn't it work?

Comment: No it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the where condition in the model class by using 'scope' 
   which receives both minimum and maximum value and returns all the cars 
   between the given range.
   Hope this helps.

In the controller, pass both minimum and maximum value to the model.

```
  if params[:searchp] || params[:searchpx] 
    @search_pricen_term = params[:searchp]
    @search_pricex_term = params[:searchpx] 
    @cars = Car.between_range(@search_pricen_term, @search_pricex_term)
  end
```

In View,

```
    <%= form_for "",url: cars_path, role: "search", method: :get do %>
       <%= text_field_tag :searchp, @search_pricen_term,placeholder: "Min..." %>
       <%= text_field_tag :searchpx, @search_pricex_term,placeholder: "Max..." %> 
       <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
     <% end %>
```

In the model,

```
     scope :between_range, -> (min, max) { where("price >= ? OR price <= ?", min, max) }
```

Comment: Thank you so much I put AND instead and it did work :)

Comment: But I have something when I put @cars = Car.order('name asc') it give me error undefined method `each' for :between_range:Symbol but when I @cars = Car.all it work

Comment: @cars = Car.order('name asc').between_range(@search_pricen_term, @search_pricex_term)
Try this. It will return the cars (with name in ascending order and between given range)